# Javascript Form Validation (new to coding)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to get some HTML form validation done using javascript, everything was working until I added the regular expression match part. Since then as soon as the submit button is hit is refreshes the page and does not do any of the form validation below it.

```html
   // ISSUE HERE
   if(refNum.value.match(/^((?!S[0-9]).)*$/)){
     text = "Please enter a valid reference number"
     error_message.innerHTML=text;
     return false;
    }
```

Above is the area I am having trouble with, it currently checks anything that does not match that pattern and outputs an error message which is what I want it to do but when it does match the pattern I want it just refreshes the page and all progress on the form is lost. The validation works fine without this area but I am required to keep it as part of a rubric and cannot find a fix. Below is the entire form validation code, I hope you can help, thankyou for your time.

```html
"use strict";
//Validate Form
function validate(){
   var refNum = document.getElementById('refNum').value;
   var error_message = document.getElementById('error_message');
   var text;
//Reference Number validation
   if(refNum.length == 0){
     text = "Please enter a reference number"
     error_message.innerHTML=text;
     return false;
   }
   else if(refNum.length < 6|| refNum.length >6){
     text = "Please enter a valid reference number"
     error_message.innerHTML=text;
     return false;
   }
   // ISSUE HERE
   if(refNum.value.match(/^((?!S[0-9]).)*$/)){
     text = "Please enter a valid reference number"
     error_message.innerHTML=text;
     return false;
    }
//Username Validation
var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
   if(userName.length <2 || userName.length > 20){
     text = "Username must be between 2 and 20 characters"
     error_message.innerHTML=text;
     return false;
   }
//Phone Number Validation
var phoneNum = document.getElementById('phoneNum').value;
  if(phoneNum.length !=10){
      text = "Please Enter a valid phone number"
      error_message.innerHTML=text;
      return false;
}

   else {
     alert(refNum)
   }
return false
}
```

Affected HTML CODE

```html
            <!--  Seminar ref num -->
            <p>
                <div class=input_field>
                <label for="refNum">Seminar ref number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="refNum" placeholder="S00000"  id="refNum"  >
                </div>
            </p>
```

Entire HTML CODE

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!-- write header comments here  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A registration page" >
    <meta name="keywords" content="Register, form, input">
    <meta name="author" content="Ethan Franks"  >
    <title>Seminar registration</title>
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="scripts/validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

require_once ("settings.php");
$conn = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$sql_db);
if (!$conn) {
  echo "<p>Failed to connect to database</p>";
}
    $page="register_page";
    include_once "header.inc";
    include_once "nav.inc";
?>


<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Register For Seminar</h2>
    <div id= "error_message"></div>
    <fieldset>
    <form id="registerForm" method="post"  onsubmit="return validate()" action="process.php">
        <!--  Seminar ref num -->
        <p>
            <div class=input_field>
            <label for="refNum">Seminar ref number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="refNum" placeholder="S00000"  id="refNum"  >
            </div>
        </p>
<!-- username -->
        <div class="input_field"
        <p>
            <label for="userName">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Username"  id="userName"  >
        </p>
        </div>

        <hr>
        <!-- Qualification level -->
    <input type="radio" id="underGraduate" name="qualLevel" value="underGraduate">
    <label for="underGraduate">Undergraduate</label><br>

    <input type="radio" id="postGraduate" name="qualLevel" value="postGraduate">
    <label for="postGraduate">Postgraduate</label><br>
        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="input_field">
        <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="johnsmith@gmail.com"  name="email">
        </div>
        <!-- Phone Number -->
        <div class="input_field">
        <p>
            <label for="phoneNum">Phone number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="phoneNum" placeholder="0000000000"  id="phoneNum"  >
        </p>
        </div>
        <!--  submit and reset -->
        <p>
            <div class="btn">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" >
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" >
            </div>
        </p>
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
    include_once "footer.inc";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share the html code as well

Comment: error from console log would be useful here

Comment: Right click on the page, goto inspect element and refer to console log (error option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

That is because you set

```
var refNum = document.getElementById('refNum').value;
```

and now you are again doing `refNum.value` which makes it

```
document.getElementById('refNum').value.value
```

You need to remove the `.value` from variable initialization like so:

```
var refNum = document.getElementById('refNum');
```